# React Component Lib + MUI: How to prevent HTML tag font-size to change Component Lib font-sizes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components, lib

By default MUI components uses REM as metric unit. It works fine from React application which you control the font-size of the HTML(root) element.

But when my Lib is imported to a project that uses a different HTML tag Font-size, it makes my Component looking off.

I would like to know the non-hackish way to prevent it. I do not want to change all components font-size value.

Thanks in advance!